# How to change session from username to id in php?

Tags: php, mysql, session

```
        // LOGIN USER
        if (isset($_POST['login_user'])) {
          $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['username']);
          $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password']);

          if (empty($username)) {
            array_push($errors, "Username is required");
          }
          if (empty($password)) {
            array_push($errors, "Password is required");
          }

          if (count($errors) == 0) {
            $password = md5($password);
            $query = "SELECT * FROM register WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
            $results = mysqli_query($db, $query);
        }   

            $qry = "SELECT * from register";
            $result = mysqli_query($qry);

            $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
            $id = $row[0];


            if (mysqli_num_rows($results) == 1) {
    //here i want to change session from username to id          
     $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
              $_SESSION['success'] = "You are now logged in";
              header('location: index.php');
            }else {
                array_push($errors, "Wrong username/password combination");
            }
          }
        ?>
```

This code is also working but i want to replace the username session to id session. Please help me how i get replace it by id.
 Here i want to set session as id from username. so please help me how i have to get the solution of my code.

Comment: Side note: Any particular reason to use MD5 passwords, as opposed to hashing them safely with `password_hash()`? or is this just for academic purposes? MD5 is not safe at all.

Comment: when i update user profile so session i get destroyed due to change the username which is set so thats why i want to replace username as session by id as session and md5 is for academic purpose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the value like this, because we are get result into an array

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

$id =  $row[0];

Correct method is below

```
// LOGIN USER
    if (isset($_POST['login_user'])) {
      $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['username']);
      $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password']);

      if (empty($username)) {
        array_push($errors, "Username is required");
      }
      if (empty($password)) {
        array_push($errors, "Password is required");
      }

      if (count($errors) == 0) {
        $password = md5($password);
        $query = "SELECT * FROM register WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
        $results = mysqli_query($db, $query);
    }   

        $qry = "SELECT * from register";
        $result = mysqli_query($qry);

        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

        // $id =  $row[0];

        $id = $row['id'];  //this is the primary key


        if (mysqli_num_rows($results) == 1) {         
          $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
          $_SESSION['success'] = "You are now logged in";
          header('location: index.php');
        }else {
            array_push($errors, "Wrong username/password combination");
        }
      }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just copy this Code :
replace your code

```
$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
```

to

```
$_SESSION['id'] = $username;
```

look like :

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($results) == 1) {
    //here i want to change session from username to id          
    $_SESSION['id'] = $username;
    $_SESSION['success'] = "You are now logged in";
    header('location: index.php');
}else {
    array_push($errors, "Wrong username/password combination");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set the `$_SESSION['id'] = $id`.